# Placing object variables in scanner

Tags: java, class, object

I'm quite new to java so any input or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to create a program that asks a user for a bunch of inputs (such as name, registration, colour, # of trips and odometer reading) for a `Car` class. I've created a car class, created an object of that class called `carSample` and given it the same variable names from my main method where i use a scanner to ask for name,registration etc...

However, this does not work and i receive the error:

> TestCar.java:8: error: ';' expected
>   String carSample.name = input.nextLine();

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input name: ");

    String carSample.name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input registration: ");

    String carSample.registration = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input colour: ");

    String carSample.colour = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input trips: ");

    int carSample.numberOfTrips = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrips; i++) {
        System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int odometerReading = input.nextInt();
    }

    car carSample = new car(); // Creates object of class Car
}

class car {
    String name;
    String registration;
    String colour;
    int numberOfTrips;
    double odometerReading;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: put the declaration of `car carSample = new car();` higher up as one of the first lines of your main method and remove the duplicate variable declaration when trying to access your objects field: `carSample.name = input.nextLine();` (<- No need to declare it as String again, you already did that in the class)

Comment: Ah that makes sense, i'll give it a shot now. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`import java.util.*;

class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        car carSample = new car(); // Creates object of class Car
    System.out.print("Input name: ");


    carSample.name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input registration: ");

     carSample.registration = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input colour: ");

 carSample.colour = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input trips: ");

 carSample.numberOfTrips = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {
        System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int odometerReading = input.nextInt();
    }


}

}
class car {
    String name;
    String registration;
    String colour;
    int numberOfTrips;
    double odometerReading;
}`
```

Try this out ... this should work ...

Comment: Also I believe you must be coming from  a javascript background based on the way you created the object. In Java , you need to create the object first before you can use it.

Comment: Just tried it now, and it works! thank you very much for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Nope, haven't touched programming at all, just started with java. Yea i understand what i did wrong, object before everything else. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
String carSample.name = input.nextLine();
```

1. carSample is declared in the car class. When you assign a value to a variable that is already declared, you don't have to specify the type. (it breaks when you do)
2. When you assign a value to a variable in an object, the object has to have been created first. Move your creation of the car object to the top of the program.

```java
...

Car carSample = new Car(); // Creates object of class Car
...
carSample.name = input.nextLine();
...
carSample.registration = input.nextLine();
...
carSample.numberOfTrips = input.nextLine();
...
carSample.name = input.nextLine();
```

Finally, when you use `numberOfTrips` in the for loop, you need to access it with `car.numberofTrips`.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much i understand what i did wrong now. I just have to declare the class and call an object before i start obtaining variables! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I moved numberOfTrips and odometerReading into CarTripHistory class. Check it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Car carSample = new Car();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input name: ");

    carSample.name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input registration: ");

    carSample.registration = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input colour: ");

    carSample.colour = input.nextLine();

    CarTripHistory carTripHistory = new CarTripHistory();

    System.out.print("Input trips: ");

    carTripHistory.numberOfTrips = input.nextInt();
    carTripHistory.odometerReading = new double[carTripHistory.numberOfTrips];

    for (int i = 0; i < carTripHistory.numberOfTrips; i++) {
        System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        carTripHistory.odometerReading[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    carSample.carTripHistory = carTripHistory;

}

class Car {
    String name;
    String registration;
    String colour;
    CarTripHistory carTripHistory;
}

class CarTripHistory{
    int numberOfTrips;
    double[] odometerReading;
}
```

Comment: oh ok, interesting might end up using this, seems more efficient. Thanks man!

Comment: Don't worry too much about efficiency, especially when you're just learning. Even professional programmers tend to value simplicity, readability, and maintainability much more than performance for the vast majority of code. With that said, your original version of the code will overwrite the previous odomoter reading with every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @Dejke I'm currently trying to print out all the information obtained from the scanner, and one of those lines is longest distance traveled, shortest distance traveled and the average distance traveled on 3 separate lines of code. Regarding what you said about overwriting each previous iteration for my loop, could i still do that? I've just done System.out.print("Longest distance travelled: " + carSample.odometerReading.MAX) That should work right? or is what you saying detrimental to finding the max and lowest value for my odometer readings. thanks

Comment: It wouldn't work as your code was originally written. One solution is to store every odometer reading in an array as @l3rutt suggests. But java doesn't have an Array.max function, you would have to work that out some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the instance of the object, imagine you have to cars **a** and **b**.
And you want them to  have different properties, each time you call `car a = new car()` you are creating a new car, with all the attributes null. And then you can use

```
 a.name = input.nextLine();
```

So with this you are giving the car a a value to the attribute name, and so on...

Although this is not the best way, because you shouldn't use the attributes directly from the car class on the other class. Instead you should create some constructors and set & get methods.